# Nikon D5100: How to keep Continuous shooting on between shots

Tags: camera-settings, nikon-d5100, shutter-release, continuous-drive

There is an old-*ish* post about the continuous release mode, but it's not exactly what I am trying to achieve, and was wondering if something has been discovered since then.

On my D5100, when I set the release mode to continuous (I am usually in A,S, or M mode), once I let go of the shutter it reverts back to single release. I would like it to stay on continuous until I put it back to single myself. Is there a way to do this? I have read mixed answers online, including on here. I want to play with auto-bracketing and creating HDR photos myself instead of using the in-camera mode for it, but I don't want to have to continuously set the release mode every time.

Comment: Are you using the ML-L3 Remote?  It does that after about a minute timeout of no operation.

Comment: No, just the shutter button. I played around wit hit this weekend, and the camera does seem to keep continuous release on after I have used it with auto bracketing. Perhaps it only goes back to single release when auto-bracketing is off. I just know it was a nuisance always having to turn it back on when I let go of the shutter to re-frame.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [D5100 user manual](http://www.nikonusa.com/pdf/manuals/dslr/D5100RM_EN.pdf), p. 216, **Release mode** under the **Shooting Menu** *should* stay set, if you're in Program Mode, or in any of A, S, or M modes.

However, as you're experiencing, it appears that either the manual is in error, or there is a logic bug in the D5100 firmware preventing it from operating as intended. Searching around for your issue:

- The asker of a similar question here ([How do I permanently set continuous mode on the Nikon D5100?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/40492/how-do-i-permanently-set-continuous-mode-on-the-nikon-d5100)) says they flip between modes frequently, and tend to use full Auto mode (for the benefit of others' use of the camera). Unfortunately, it's not clear if the poster verified if Continuous Release mode stays set between shots when using P, S, A, or M modes.
- The start of the dpreview.com thread, [D5100 - Can it "remember" my release mode?](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/3255626), asks the same question, and similarly to the previous Photo.SE question above, is using Auto or Auto Flash mode. But one of the responders indicates that the camera won't remember the setting in P mode.

Because the D5100 was released over 7 years ago, and because there has been only 1 firmware update (which was to correct how the camera treated the updated EN-EL14a battery vs. the existing EN-EL14 battery), I wouldn't keep any hope that the behavior will ever be fixed by Nikon. =(

Comment: On my D5100 if I set the mode to continuous on the “on screen” setting, it returns to single mode afterwards - however if I change it in the settings-menu it stays on even after I fire the trigger. I assume that some of the “on screen settings” are temporary and returns to the “menu settings” after release. It does it as well when the shutter is set to “Delay”.

Comment: @ssn Interesting. Have you tested the setting when done in P/A/S/M mode, vs other auto scene modes?

Comment: Hmm just tried it out now, and seemingly it only switches from Delayed back to “normal” (whether that being single or continuous). When I switch between continuous and single it doesn’t switch back and forth. So guess it doesn’t help OP at all :-)